# Select row based on dynmically created value

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have a sql table below, value of column parameter and parameter value are dynamically created. The design below is cater for additional parameter being added in later stage. So I think using the parameter and parameter value as column is not ideal for such design.

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Parameter      | Parameter Value  |     Computers    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          Phase      |         New      |         PC1      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          Phase      |         New      |         PC2      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          Phase      |   Redevelopment  |         PC3      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          Cost       |         High     |         PC1      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          Cost       |         High     |         PC2      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          Cost       |         Cost     |         PC3      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Given a scenario where a user search by Phase = "New" AND Cost = "High", it will result in PC1.

At this moment, I could think of is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM projectParameter 
WHERE Parameter = 'Phase' AND Value = 'New' AND Parameter = 'Cost' AND Value = 'High'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean `where Parameter = 'Cost' and Parameter Value = 'High'`?

Comment: @SomeBody - No, because that condition applies to only one row at a time, but the OP is asking how to apply the conditions across a group of rows *(return all groups that contain a `P='Cost' AND 'PV='High'` row AND contain a `P='Phase' AND PV='New'`row.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, it seems you want list of all computers where there is computer entry for both below conditions :

- Parameter = 'Cost' AND Parameter Value = 'High'
- Parameter = 'Phase' AND Parameter Value = 'New'

You can try below sql query to see it results your need :

```
SELECT t.computer
FROM table t
WHERE t.parameter = 'cost'
    AND t.parameter_value = 'high'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT computer FROM table where computer=t.computer AND parameter = 'phase' AND parameter_value = 'new');
```

Comment: Can this support more parameter I.e. Type of Computer, Owner of Computer, etc due to dynamically created?

Comment: @johny Yeah sure, you can have multiple EXISTS clauses appended to current query. This can help with multiple parameter/parameter value pairs you need.

Answer (score 1):

First, select all rows that match any part of your filtering.

Then aggregate all those rows to get one result per computer.

Then check each result to see if it contains all the required filtering contraints.

```
SELECT
  Computers
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  (Parameter = 'Phase' AND ParameterValue = 'New')
  OR
  (Parameter = 'Cost'  AND ParameterValue = 'High')
GROUP BY
  Computers
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: This will not work correctly in case if there are two entries for same computer with parameter = 'cost' and parametervalue='high' or vice versa with 'phase'. However for unique entries for cost/phase per each computer this will work just fine.

Comment: @Jasmeet - The solution to that is to clean the data of duplicates; either deleting the from the table, or introducing a nested query to de-duplicate the data before querying it.  Similarly, if there are duplicates in the table, your query would return that computer multiple times, and the solution would be the same.

Comment: Hi, My desire was to have two criteria included (AND) 
thanks.